# SwiftUI: NavigationLink weird behaviour

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build a store in order to navigate in a SwifUI flow.
The idea is that every screen should observe the state and push into the next one using a NavigationLink.

It seems to work for pushing one view, but a soon as I push several views into the stack, it starts behaving oddly: the view pops itself.

Luckily I was able to reproduce it in a separate project. When I move from 2 to 3, the third screen appears but the NavigationView resets to it's original state (`ContentView`):

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct NavigationTestApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
            }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}



class Store: ObservableObject{
    @Published var state: StoreState
    
    struct StoreState {
        var flowState: FlowState = .none
    }
    
    enum FlowState {
        case none, one, two, three
    }
    
    enum Action {
        case moveTo1, moveTo2, moveTo3
    }
    
    init(state: StoreState) {
        self.state = state
    }
    
    func send(_ action: Action) {
        
        switch action {
        case .moveTo1:
            state.flowState = .one
        case .moveTo2:
            state.flowState = .two
        case .moveTo3:
            state.flowState = .three
        }
    }
    
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var store = Store(state: .init())
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                store.send(.moveTo1)
            }, label: {
                Text("moveTo1")
            })
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ContentView1().environmentObject(store),
                isActive: Binding(
                    get: { store.state.flowState == .one },
                    set: { _ in
                    }
                ),
                label: {}
            )
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                store.send(.moveTo2)
            }, label: {
                Text("moveTo2")
            })
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ContentView2().environmentObject(store),
                isActive: Binding(
                    get: { store.state.flowState == .two },
                    set: { _ in
                    }
                ),
                label: {}
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                store.send(.moveTo3)
            }, label: {
                Text("moveTo3")
            })
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ContentView3().environmentObject(store),
                isActive: Binding(
                    get: { store.state.flowState == .three },
                    set: { _ in
                    }
                ),
                label: {}
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView3: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try with `.isDetailLink(false)` as in, for ex., https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707193/12299030

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution. The issue seems to be that your model pops the previous view from the stack when you "move to" the next. I modified it (slightly) so that the system now can determine which views need to be on the navigation stack.

I have to admit, though, that I would have expected that your example would work, since we are just declaring which (single) view is on the stack.

So, the slightly modified code which keeps the previous views on the navigation stack (I also sprinkled in some print statements to see what's going on):

```
import SwiftUI

class Store: ObservableObject{
    @Published var state: StoreState

    struct StoreState {
        var flowState: FlowState = .none
    }

    enum FlowState: Int {
        case none = 0, one, two, three
    }

    enum Action {
        case moveTo1, moveTo2, moveTo3
    }

    init(state: StoreState) {
        self.state = state
    }

    func send(_ action: Action) {
        print("state: \(state), action: \(action)")
        switch action {
        case .moveTo1:
            state.flowState = .one
        case .moveTo2:
            state.flowState = .two
        case .moveTo3:
            state.flowState = .three
        }
        print("new state: \(state)")
    }


}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var store = Store(state: .init())


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("moveTo1")
                store.send(.moveTo1)
            }, label: {
                Text("moveTo1")
            })
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ContentView1().environmentObject(store),
                isActive: Binding(
                    get: { store.state.flowState.rawValue >= Store.FlowState.one.rawValue },
                    set: { newValue in
                        store.state.flowState = .none
                        print("ContentView1: \(newValue)")
                    }
                ),
                label: {}
            )
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("moveTo2")
                store.send(.moveTo2)
            }, label: {
                Text("moveTo2")
            })

            NavigationLink(
                destination: ContentView2().environmentObject(store),
                isActive: Binding(
                    get: { store.state.flowState.rawValue >= Store.FlowState.two.rawValue },
                    set: { newValue in
                        store.state.flowState = .one
                        print("ContentView2: \(newValue)")
                    }
                ),
                label: {}
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("moveTo3")
                store.send(.moveTo3)
            }, label: {
                Text("moveTo3")
            })

            NavigationLink(
                destination: ContentView3().environmentObject(store),
                isActive: Binding(
                    get: { store.state.flowState.rawValue >= Store.FlowState.three.rawValue },
                    set: { newValue in
                        store.state.flowState = .two
                        print("ContentView3: \(newValue)")
                    }
                ),
                label: {}
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView3: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store

    var body: some View {

        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}


import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    NavigationView {
        ContentView()
    }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
)
```

**Notes:**

It will be probably better to add an event (aka action) `back` and determine the new state in the view model, instead letting it doing from the view.

Comment: Keeping all the navigation links active! That's it! 
Thanks a lot :-)